# Force an intermediary page for all off-site links in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

This [page lists a number of security issues](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8011/396) to be aware of when redirecting a user off your primary website.

How can I hook into the ASP.NET MVC "pipeline" to detect when a hyperlink is being created, and alter it so that it goes to a redirection page such as `https://host.com/redirect.aspx?http://yourlink.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any easy way to directly modify all links created by your View code, so it really depends on how much work you're willing to do.

Assuming your users have javascript enabled, the easiest way would probably be to use jQuery to scan your page for links and modify them as appropriate. That way, none of your other code has to change.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/find-select-all-external-links-with.html

Another approach would be to have a policy of always creating external links by invoking a specific extension method:

```
@Html.ExternalLink("Click here", "http://www.google.com")
```

This introduces more maintenance overhead, but at least it consolidates the redirect code itself to one place where you could easily change it if you need to at some point in the future.

Comment: +1 I like the approach as a backup, but would prefer to have the links natively written out